# Javascript .push not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I've been completely stumped by this bit of code here. Basically, I'm trying to go through an array of Word objects, and organize them based on word type using a switch statement. This is all triggered by jQuery waiting for a button to be pressed.

```
for (var i=0; i<wordList.length; i++)
{
    switch (wordList[i].type) {
        case "1": nouns.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        //"1" is the type flag for noun, the "word" property is the string containing the word
        ... //Rest of word types
    }
}
```

The word wouldn't actually get assigned to the nouns array. So I changed the case "1" line to this:

```
case "1": nouns.push(wordList[i].word); asdf = nouns; asdf2 = wordList[i].word; break;
```

Without var, asdf and asdf2 became implicitly global, so I could play with them in console:

```
asdf
asdf2
```

returned [] and "I" respectively, so it could pick up the word, but it didn't add it to the array.

```
asdf.push(asdf2)
```

Returned 1 and the next log of asdf gave me ["I"].

What's wrong here?

Edit: Full relevant code

```
//Declare arrays
var articles=[], properNouns=[], nouns=[], pluralNouns=[], adjectives=[], conjunctions=[], verbs=[], pluralVerbs=[], adverbs=[], prepositions=[], interrogatives=[];

//Sort words into proper arrays
for (var i=0; i<wordList.length; i++)
{
    switch (wordList[i].type) {
        case "1": nouns.push(wordList[i].word); asdf = nouns; asdf2 = wordList[i].word; break;
        case "11": pluralNouns.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "12": properNouns.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "2": verbs.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "21": pluralVerbs.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "3": adjectives.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "4": adverbs.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "5": conjunctions.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "6": prepositions.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "7": interrogatives.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        case "8": articles.push(wordList[i].word); break;
        default: console.log("Error, could not sort "+wordList[i].word); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: how is nouns declared?

Comment: yes, please show full code...

Comment: I have edited to include all the code I think could be relevant. If you would like more, please let me know

Comment: Show us your wordList declaration, please.

Comment: I unfortunately believe I will have to close/delete this question, because I don't think I can find a satisfactory explanation. It turns out the issue was caused somewhere entirely different in the filesystem which didn't even contain any script, and I suspect that it has to do with a subversion bug of some sort. If I can find the exact cause, and it has potential to help someone else with a similar issue, I'll post it. Otherwise I'm taking this down. Thanks for your assistance, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZLWW/2/) example.

The only changes made from your code to the example:

- definition of wordList
- in jsfiddle example a div tag to append output to

It appears to do what you want. Is your definition of wordList different?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //Declare arrays
    var articles = [], properNouns = [], nouns = [], pluralNouns = [], adjectives = [], conjunctions = [], verbs = [], pluralVerbs = [], adverbs = [], prepositions = [], interrogatives = [];

    var wordList = [{ 'type': "1", 'word': 'foo' },
         { 'type': "1", 'word': 'foo1' },
         { 'type': "1", 'word': 'foo2'}, 
         { 'type': "1", 'word': 'foo3' }];

    //Sort words into proper arrays
    for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
        switch (wordList[i].type) {
            case "1":
                nouns.push(wordList[i].word);
                asdf = nouns;
                asdf2 = wordList[i].word;
                break;
            case "11":
                pluralNouns.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "12":
                properNouns.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "2":
                verbs.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "21":
                pluralVerbs.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "3":
                adjectives.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "4":
                adverbs.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "5":
                conjunctions.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "6":
                prepositions.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "7":
                interrogatives.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            case "8":
                articles.push(wordList[i].word);
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Error, could not sort " + wordList[i].word);
                break;
        }
    }
    for (var i in nouns) {
        console.log(nouns[i]);
        $('#output').append(nouns[i] + '<br>');
    }
    console.log(nouns);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The word list is defined sort of like that but it traverses down a tree of objects and arrays to get to that point. Unfortunately, I have confirmed that the issue was a matter of a messed up copy of a data file somewhere else in the system. I appreciate everyone's help, though! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Cause of the problem:**
A data file had been modified and the VERBS were no longer tagged correctly, leading to no sentences being generated

**Why the array was empty:**
The system used to process the arrays **emptied** them, and the new variable `asdf` merely **pointed** to the array, which was empty by the time I used it in console

**How I could have avoided a lot of this:**

```
case "1": nouns.push(wordList[i].word); asdf = nouns.slice(0); break;
```

Let this be a Public Service Announcement. Copy your array during debug.

Answer (score 1):

Yep - digging up an old thread...

I had this same problem today. Took me a while to figure out that I had a Watch Expression in Chrome Debugger that emptied the array..

so code to push looked like this:

```
$scope.emailMsg.Bcc.push(EmailAddress);
```

Watch expression in debugger like this

```
$scope.emailMsg.Bcc = [];
```

So - every time I stepped my array would zero out :)